# GLSL 3.3 resources

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm quite familiar with OpenGL 3.3 through the help of the OpenGL Super Bible(5). I found it to be a great book to learn the core API. However, it only gets around to some very basic usage of shaders.

The next step seems to be to learn more tricks to put into the shader pipeline, but I can't find much beyond what's already covered in the Super Bible. This includes some basic lighting, texture sampling and post effects like blurring and glow.

The orange book seems a bit outdated, using version 1.4 of GLSL. Is it still relevant despite its age? Does it cover anything regarding the geometry shader's uses, and how much would I be "missing out" on from the 3.30 GLSL?

I'd rather avoid reading about or using deprecated parts of GLSL and I'd prefer answers to focus on 3.3 GLSL, unless it's easily translated into later versions.

I'm looking for guides, tutorials and code snippets, on the web or in book form.

Comment: "It's 6 years old by now, and it's using the 1.5 shading language." That's not possible. GLSL 1.50 is from OpenGL version 3.2. See, there's a big gap between GLSL 1.50 and 3.30 because the ARB (the governors of OpenGL) realized that it was *really stupid* to have the GLSL versions be different from the corresponding OpenGL versions. GLSL 1.50 maps to GL 3.2, and that was the last version with the mis-matching version numbers. The Orange book version 3 covers GL 3.1 and therefore GLSL 1.40. It's certainly not "6 years old".

Comment: I saw a publication date saying 2006, but that may have been an older edition. Feel a bit dumb that I can't find where I saw it now.. Anyway, I'm aware of the version number jump. Isn't there still quite a bit of deprecated and changed functionality between 1.40 and 3.30?

Comment: It was the second edition, which is 2006. The third edition (current) was published 2009

Comment: "Isn't there still quite a bit of deprecated and changed functionality between 1.40 and 3.30?" Added functionality, yes. *Changed*, as in something that worked before stops working now? No. And certainly nothing removed. The only gap in OpenGL where functionality was actually removed was the GL 3.0 to 3.1 gap.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. You're welcome to post an answer stating that the orange book is indeed relevant still and how it'd be a good next step from the very basics. Any other resource suggestion is also appreciated!

Comment: 3.30 is essentially the "peak" in the size of the language with all old things supported and nothing deprecated.  4.0 deprecates lots of stuff (though it may still all be available if your GL implementation supports compatability mode)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Um no. What you said is completely wrong. Please stop spreading disinformation. For the record, [deprecation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Deprecation) was introduced in OpenGL 3.**0**, not 3.3. Most of the deprecated functionality was *removed* in 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "GPU Gems" series of books. The first three volumes are available for free at the NVidia developer website:

[GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_pref01.html)

[GPU Gems 2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_frontmatter.html)

[GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_pref01.html)

Comment: +1 Alhough the example code is often in other shading languages, like Cg or HLSL, the basic concepts are always the same and the shading languages are very similar in syntax, anyway.